# Subtracting Integer from Date returning previous date than expected date

Tags: apex, date, timezone

We are trying to calculate "Date A" by subtracting 5 days from "Date B".

For e.g

Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2021, 06, 26);
Date newDate = mydate.addDays(-5);
System.debug('output::'+newDate);

Output is 2021-06-20 00:00:00 expected output should be 2021-06-21 00:00:00

It might be because offset is added as 00:00:00. Any leads on how to proceed in order to work it for any user or profile correctly irrespective of timezone.

Comment: have you checked time zone of the user executing this? It generally happens because of the user's time zone. Actual value is 5 days less only but because of the time zone it shows up a different value.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Date rather than Datetime? A date should output with no time part.

Comment: BTW timezones are only relevant to Datetime values. A date is without timezone until converted to Datetime.

Answer (score 2):

`System.debug` outputs times in GMT by default, but `Date.newInstance` and `DateTime.newInstance` are affected by the user's time zone setting. Use the GMT versions instead, or use the appropriate format methods to get the value back out in the user's local time zone, despending on what you're doing exactly.

```
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2021, 06, 26); 
Date newDate = mydate.addDays(-5); 
System.debug('output::'+newDate.format());
```

Or:

```
Date myDate = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2021, 06, 26).date(); 
Date newDate = mydate.addDays(-5); 
System.debug('output::'+newDate);
```

Comment: It's frustrating sometimes that we have to deal with time zones even for `Dates`, but we cannot escape